# R - How to format list of methods in Reference Class?

Tags: r, function, class, methods

I have a more complicated Reference Class that I've whittled down to the code below:

```
make_LD <- setRefClass("Longitudinal_Data",
                       methods = list(
                         populator <- function() {
                           print("Working")
                         }))
make_LD$populator()

Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
  ‘populator’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “refGeneratorSlot”
```

But getting the above error. It's not clear to me at all what I'm missing. The method `populator` shows up under `make_LD$methods()` but not under `make_LD$getClass()`. I've tried several different variable names for the method.

Answer (score 1):

`make_LD` is a constructor! You use it to make an object and you can then use that object.
To check, use this code

```
make_LD <- setRefClass("make_LD",
                       methods = list(
                         populator = function() {
                           print("Working")
                         }
                       ))
mkld <- make_LD()
mkld$populator()
```

Comment: also use "=" instead "<-"